# How to copy nested folders to multiple destinations? (unix, bash, mac)

Tags: bash, mac, unix

Given a folder structure, such as:

```
/Parent-Folder
  /Child-Folder
    /Child-Child-Folder
  ...
```

How do I copy/paste all child folders to a list of destinations, such as:

```
Dest Folder/
Dest Folder2/
Dest Folder3/
```

Comment: What OS? What command interpreter?

Comment: @music2myear Thanks - adjusted the title/tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a combination of two posts. One related to [recursively moving folders](https://superuser.com/questions/222395/copy-a-directory-on-unix) and another related to [generating a list of folders](https://superuser.com/questions/1127487/how-to-automatically-create-folders-from-a-list-in-mac-os-x/1127728).

1. Create a text file with all paths listed on separate lines. Each path should be in quotes to avoid special character errors. For example, `destinations.txt` could look like:

```
"Dest Folder/"
"Dest Folder2/"
"Dest Folder3/"
```

2. Run the following in the terminal:

```
xargs -tI % cp -r "parent-folder/" % < destinations.txt
```

**How it Works**

`xargs -tI % [command] % < [file]`

This portion calls a command for each line in a file.

`cp -r source/ dest/`

This is the command being repeated. It recursively copies the contents of the source folder to a destination folder.